# PostgreSQL: How to get all records after particular tagging or status and timestamp?

Tags: postgresql

Need help on this..

I want to get all records after specific records using timestamp

What i have is:

**Table_1**

`Records        Status`

```
ABCDE01         A
ABCDE02         B
```

**Table_2**

`Records         History_Status       Date`

```
ABCDE01         Q                    2017-09-01
ABCDE01         A                    2017-09-02
ABCDE01         B                    2017-09-03

ABCDE02         Q                    2017-09-01
ABCDE02         A                    2017-09-02
ABCDE02         B                    2017-09-03  
ABCDE02         C                    2017-09-04
ABCDE02         A                    2017-09-05
```

Based on the given sample, i need to get all the records from **Table_2** with other history_status not equal to status of **Table_1** and after the Date.

**Sample result:**

`Records         History_Status       Date`

```
ABCDE01         B                    2017-09-03
ABCDE02         C                    2017-09-04
ABCDE02         A                    2017-09-05
```

Thanks in advance!! ^_^

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what is the problem with the query you tried?

Comment: I tried row_number() over (partition by records order by "date" desc) , tried joins but doesnt result what i need,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use window functions. Just join the tables using `records` and place your criteria in WHERE clause:

```
select records, history_status, date
from table_1
join table_2 using(records)
where status <> history_status
and date > '2017-09-02'
order by records, date;
```

---

If you want to find a limit date for each `records` separately, you can use a common table expression to find these limit dates. Note that `distinct on(records)` is used in the second query in case there are more than one row with `status = history_status`.

```
with joined_tables as (
    select *
    from table_1
    join table_2 using(records)
),
limit_dates as (
    select distinct on(records) records, date as limit_date
    from joined_tables
    where status = history_status
    order by records, date desc
)
select j.records, history_status, date
from joined_tables j
join limit_dates l on j.records = l.records
where status <> history_status
and date > limit_date
order by j.records, date;

 records | history_status |    date    
---------+----------------+------------
 ABCDE01 | B              | 2017-09-03
 ABCDE02 | C              | 2017-09-04
 ABCDE02 | A              | 2017-09-05
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Hi @Klin, is it possible  to use the date as date >  date of history_status = status?